# What's wrong in elasticsearch aggregation query and how can I get all items from db?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I started working with elasticsearch only few days ago, and composing queries it seems to be a little hell for me. And now I'm stuck on aggregation functionality. Please, help me, I'll be very grateful :).

1) I have db of books (Genre, Author, Book), and I need to get all Books where Genre = incoming value of genre and Author = incoming value of author. I use aggregation, but seems not right, because every time regardless of incoming values I get the same array of books (furthermore I have field IsComplete and need to get only items where IsComplete = true).
Here is my code:

```
var aggregationName = "books";

var search = elasticClient.Search<BooksItemDto>(b => b
            .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
            .Must(_ => _.Term(t => t.OnField(tf => tf.IsComplete).Value(true)) &&
                  _.MatchPhrase(t => t.OnField(tf => tf.Author.Equals(author))) &&
                  _.MatchPhrase(t => t.OnField(tf => tf.Genre.Equals(genre)))))).Size(0)
            .Aggregations(_ => _.Terms(aggregationName, t => t.Field(f => f.BookName))));
```

than I take items from the Nest.Bucket and it looks like the query gives me the first 10 of all books, but not specific books. So, what's wrong in this query?

2) Elasticsearch returns me only 10 items (by default), but I need all items. What I need add to code to get all items from db?

Thanks for answers).

Comment: do you need the hits or the count?

Comment: I wanna get a collection of all items to throw it to UI, the count I'll take from this collection. And I don't know how many items may be in db at this moment.